# How to receive data via bluetooth on Raspberry Pi and transfer it to USB port

Tags: usb, bluetooth, data-transfer

I would like to know the way by which the data received on raspberry pi via Bluetooth from some other device can be transferred to a flash drive connected to the USB port of raspberry Pi.

Comment: What sort of data? How is it received? as a file? why can you not just saved the data to the USB drive as a file?

Comment: what i mean is sending a file from my phone to Raspberry Pi using Bluetooth and then storing that to a flash drive connected to raspberry pi's USB port.

Comment: So your question is really along the lines of what software do I install on the RPi to receive files via bluetooth from my phone?

Comment: Its not that much simple, i don't want to use a monitor, i want it automatic
I connect my phone to Raspberry Pi via BLUETOOTH and whenever i send some file then that will get stored in the flash drive connected to the USB port of Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

```
obexpushd
```

from a location on the flash drive then any files it receives will be saved there.

Comment: Hi Can you explain a bit more or where can i get more info. I tried searchlight but its so little info about this.

Comment: google obexpushd and you get lots of examples and blogs talking about how to use it.

Comment: will it work like this, whenever i connect any Flash Drive to USB port of Raspberry Pi then without the help of any monitor whenever i want i can send data from any BLUETOOTH enabled device to the flash drive and the data will get stored there?

Comment: yes, as long as the drive was set up priory to starting the obxepushd server from that drive, that you could do on boot or key press or time or any other trigger. You may be able to start the server on detection of a specific drive.

Comment: okay i think i got it. I shall test this with my friend.